# How to avoid additional re-arranging page once it is loaded?

Tags: jquery, image

```
<body>
<img id='imgT' src='<?php echo $folder;?>/01.jpg' alt="img">

<script>
    $("#imgT").css("height" , 90 + "vh");  // I need to avoid scrolling to see the entire image.
    var a = $("#imgT").width() + 3;
    alert (a); // result is 3 instead of real width
    $("#container").css("width", a);
</script>

...
</body>
```

In css file there is nothing about `imgT`, except `display:block;`.

So, in this scenario js shows `0` as `imgT` width, i.e. doesn't see it.

When I place js code inside a separate .js file, everything works fine, except ugly image re-sizing at the end of page loading.

I want to avoid this additional re-aranging page once it is loaded, i.e. to make this re-sizing just after image is loaded, but javascript doesn't see its width properly.

Any help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your code runs after the image element is being created, however the loading of the image inside is asynchronous. you need to wait until the image inside the `<img>` is fully loaded, only then JavaScript will report the correct measurements:

```
<script>
    $(window).load(function() {
        $("#imgT").css("height", 90 + "vh"); // I need to avoid scrolling to see the entire image.
        var a = $("#imgT").width() + 3;
        alert(a); // result is 3 instead of real width
        $("#container").css("width", a);
    });
</script>
```

the `$(window).load(function() {` clause is being executed only after all the asynchronous elements like `<iframe>` and `<img>` are being fully loaded

Comment: Banana, thanks, I understand, but this doesn't solve the problem. Additional page re-arranging remains, using `$(window).load`

Comment: then i might have misunderstood the question, what do you mean by 'additional rearranging' ?

Comment: Once the page is loaded, changing the size of `imgT` everything is moved up or down, left or right, depending on starting `imgT` size. I want to prevent an end-user to see this. It looks unprofessional.

Comment: i see, well if the only reason you dont want things rearranged is that so the user wouldnt have to see all this, you could use a black screen overlay div that would fade away once everything is fully loaded, and stick a 'Loading..' on it... ?

Comment: You mean black screen overlay div over the `body`, and the remove it using `$(window).load()` ?

Comment: Banana, looking at the overly div is a bit more comfortable than looking at the re-arranging page, but it is also far of perfect impression. Anyway, I see it is the only solution. Thanks again.

Comment: Youre welcome mate, note that you can restyle it to be more professional, you can add stuff that users can read while its loading.

Comment: Oh, that's much better. I have now tons of solutions. Just now, I can say - SOLVED. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want no rearanging you have to get the width with php and insert it. So:
`$sizes = getimagesize($folder . "/01.jpg"); width = sizes[0];`
Also you have to calculate the hight with php.

Comment: Mainz007, what after getting the width and the height of the image? How can I change the width of `#container` using php ? Because this changing is the main reason of re-arranging the page at the end.

Comment: The way you use short php code in the src of your image you can also use it in the script. So `$("#container").css("width", <?php $myWidth; ?>);`

Comment: Mainz007, the `width` of `imgT` is dynamic, i.e. it is valid only after changing its `height`, according to viewport. So I use `$("#imgT").css("height" , 90 + "vh");` AFTER THAT I need to calculate `imgT` width. And I believe it's not possible to get users's viewport height via php.